# Does iOS maintain a system log of personal hotspot connections?

Tags: ios, filesystem, jailbreak, tethering

I was wondering if iOS maintains a timestamped record of devices which have connected to a personal hotspot anywhere within its system files?

Something like *x* MAC address connected at *y* time.

I can jailbreak to gain access if necessary, but won’t do it if such a record doesn’t exist.

Any advice you can provide is greatly appreciated.